# Unable to Run [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember within PowerShell Function

Tags: powershell, com, ole

I've been trying to write a program to access properties and methods of a 3rd party OLE DLL.

Below code runs fine.

```
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("AppName", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $appObj, $null)
```

As the invocation is going to be repetitive, I want to call a wrapper like below.

```
function Get-Property {
  param(
    $objOLE,
    [String] $propertyName
  )
  [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember($propertyName,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty,$null,$objOLE,$null)
}
```

When the script runs

```
Get-Property($appObj, "AppName")
```

I got this error:

```
Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Method 'System.__ComObject.ToString' not found."
At F:\Scripts\test.ps1:21 char:36
+   [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember <<<< ($propertyName,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty,$null,$objOLE,$null)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

This is confusing. Anybody has an insight? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Remember your function is a PowerShell function/command and not a .NET method i.e. don't use parens and don't comma separate args:

```
Get-Property $appObj AppName
```

The way you had it, your function gets one argument that is an array with two elements.